# RStudio - Update e adicionação de novos dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-excel, r, dplyr

Olá,

Estou buscando dados do IBGE (`library("sidrar")`),

```
df <- get_sidra (api = "/t/1846/n1/all/v/all/p/all/c11255/90707/d/v585%200")
#Selecionando as colunas que me interessa
df1 <- df[,c(7,10,13)]
```

Isso me retorna a série histórica do PIB

```
df1 <- Trimestre (Código)           Setores e subsetores           Valor
        199601                      PIB a preço de mercado         189323
        ...                             ...                         ...
        201903                      PIB a preço de mercado         1842700
        201904                      PIB a preço de mercado         1842740
```

E salvo este arquivo no meu computador

```
read.xlsx("df1.xlsx", sheetName = "PIB", header = TRUE)
```

Ao sair um novo dado, 202001, o IBGE revisa 3 dados anteriores (201902, 201903, 201904) e divulga o 202001,

então rodo apenas o código para buscar os 4 últimos dados, para evitar ter que buscar a série completa

```
df2 <- get_sidra (api = "/t/1846/n1/all/v/all/p/last%203/c11255/90707/d/v585%200")
```

Após ter o meu df2, quero dar update nos dados de 201902, 201903 e 201904, e adicionar os dados de 202001

Para adicionar apenas o novo dado, estava utilizando :

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("df1.xlsx")
addDataFrame(df2,getSheets(wb)$df2,  col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, startRow = nrow(read.xlsx("df1.xlsx", sheetName = "PIB"))+2)
saveWorkbook(wb,"df1.xlsx")
```

Mas essa função não me ajuda a dar update nas informações anteriores. Alguém poderia me dizer de qual maneira consigo fazer isso?

Comment: Favor ler [Como criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/824/75104) e criar um [mcve]

Comment: Você precisa usar XLS? Se está lidando com grandes bases de informações que precisam de atualização regular, é mais eficiente usar um formato de banco de dados. Recomendo SQL, que pode ser acessado pelo Excel e possui pacotes amigáveis para R (como dbplyr). Se realmente precisa usar XLS, atualize sua pergunta com um exemplo mínimo reproduzível e indique o pacote que está usando para exportar os dados.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta Seria XLS mesmo, obrigada pela ajuda. Sou nova aqui e acabei fazendo a pergunta de maneira errada, irei atualizar a pergunta de acordo com o que Daniel Takeshi enviou.

Obrigada pela ajuda
Agradeço

Comment: Não sei se entendi corretamente a dúvida. Mas ao que parece você quer unir arquivos de meses diferentes e não pode usar os arquivos que foram baixados anteriormente pois eles podem ter sido alterados. Partindo do princípio que esses dados são baixados separadamente em escala mensal e que contem o mesmo tipo de informação, não bastaria um `rbind`?